# RestSharp - Output file download result in browser

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm quite new to using RestSharp and I've got a question that I can't find an answer to here on SO.

I've have this situation where I must download a csv-file and output the file directly in the browser. The following code illustrates how to download a file and save it to a certain path on disc.

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var writer = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
{
    var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest("Assets/LargeFile.7z");
    request.ResponseWriter = (responseStream) => responseStream.CopyTo(writer);
    var response = client.DownloadData(request);
}
```

I want to download the csv-file and directly output the result as a download file in the browser. You know, like in Chrome the file you download will be displayed in the left bottom corner of your browser.

Can this be done using RestSharp? And if so, how? Got an example? Please share it. ;-)

Thanx!